# Trying to compile GnuPG-2.1.1 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: macos, x86-64, gnupg, build-error, unix-ar

While trying to build the latest GnuPG (2.1.1 *modern*), my build fails when trying to link `t-stringhelp`. `make` outputs:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file libcommon.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): libcommon.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_compare_filenames", referenced from:
      _main in t-stringhelp.o
  "_make_absfilename_try", referenced from:
      _main in t-stringhelp.o
  "_make_filename_try", referenced from:
      _main in t-stringhelp.o
  "_percent_escape", referenced from:
      _main in t-stringhelp.o
  "_strconcat", referenced from:
      _main in t-stringhelp.o
  "_xstrconcat", referenced from:
      _main in t-stringhelp.o
```

I don't know how to fix this as `libcommon` is part of the source, so it should build fine. When building with `CFLAGS="-m64"` (`-arch x86_64` does nothing), I get this:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ../common/libgpgrl.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../common/libgpgrl.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gnupg_rl_initialize", referenced from:
      _main in gpg.o
```

I've also rebuilt all the depandancies (as I built them on Mavericks), except `pinentry`, as it can't find `libiconv` which is also installed.  My `configure` outputs that its target is `Darwin (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0)`, so this should work. I have also got all the latest prerequisites, tried to install everything in its own directory (--prefix=/usr/local/gnupg-2.1.1), build all the dependancies and GnuPG as 32 bits (again, fails on same error), created a separate build folder and tried to build in there, but only one thing so far has solved the error: looking at how `libgpgrl.a` is being built - it's only component is `common/gpgrlhelp.c` - so I `cd`'ed into `g10` and tried to build `gpg2`, replacing `../common/libgpgrl.a` with `../common/gpgrlhelp.o`, the `lib common.a` with all of its object files, for all the libraries that didn't work. Then some programs weren't linking to `libksba` `libgcrypt` and `libassuan`, so I changed the Makefiles, so that they could link. I can now compile all the code well, I installed everything, but I get a new error, when I try to run `gpg2`:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __gcry_mpi_init
  Referenced from: /usr/local/gnupg-2.1.1/lib/libgcrypt.20.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __gcry_mpi_init
  Referenced from: /usr/local/gnupg-2.1.1/lib/libgcrypt.20.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have everything in my path, which is:

```
/usr/local/gnupg-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/gnupg-2.1.1/lib:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

I could compile GnuPG-2.0.22 on Mavericks, but no version of GnuPG builds on Yosemite.

Please help, I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had a `ranlib` in `/usr/local/bin/ranlib`. It was broken, I don't know how it got there (I did try to build gcc at some point, it doesn't support `make uninstall`, so that's probably why). I just ran:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/ranlib /usr/local/ranlib_old
```

Then I just rebuilt all the dependancies, and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I’ve been running GnuPG 2.1 on [Yosemite 10.10.2](http://9to5mac.com/2014/12/20/os-x-yosemite-beta-14c81h/) (the latest public beta of as of this writing) for about a week and it’s been fine.

You can follow [these directions](https://github.com/mtigas/homebrew-gpg21) for using `brew tap` or you can use the raw URL: `brew install https://github.com/mtigas/homebrew-gpg21/raw/master/Formula/gnupg2.rb`.

Note this formula installs **GnuPG 2.1**; not GnuPG 2.1.1, the version originally asked about. I can confirm [this bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/gnupg-users@gnupg.org/msg26136.html) where `gpg2 --refresh-keys` fails with some keyservers using 2.1 (apparently [fixed in 2.1.1](https://www.mail-archive.com/gnupg-users@gnupg.org/msg26193.html)) but it’ll get you 90% there.

It shouldn’t be hard to update the formula to install 2.1.1.

**Update**
Someone submitted a pull request for GNuPG 2.1.1 support—I just tried it and it worked great. Short answer: `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/calebthompson/homebrew-gpg21/2.1.1/Formula/gnupg2.rb`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I've just worked out that I had a `ranlib` in `/usr/local/bin/ranlib`, which was broken. I renamed it to `/usr/local/bin/ranlib_old`, the running `make clean` then `make` works fine, but I the same errors as I have described above (to do with `dyld`, but I'm planning to rebuild all the dependancies with `/usr/bin/ranlib`). Thank you for answering, I will add further details soon.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would install `homebrew`, which is a one-liner pasted from their website (http://brew.sh)  then do

```
brew install gnupg
```

If therw are any problems, run

```
brew doctor
```

and heed the good doctor's advice.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I was hoping to get GnuPG built myself, so that I can fix similar future errors and use homebrew as a last resort.

Comment: You can always take a look at the formula in homebrew to see how they are building it and then adapt as needed to your own needs.

Comment: I did take a look at homebrew's formula for GnuPG, but unfortunately they are using an older version of GnuPG, which I have also attempted to build, but with no success.